# Does Safari 6 Inspector show CSS inheritance chain?

Tags: css, safari

I have not been able to find a list of an element's CSS Style Rule inheritance in the Mac Safari 6 Inspector. Does such a thing exist?

ADD: I've seen a semblance of it but it still seems severely limited compared to the Chrome counterpart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's there under the `{}` section of the right-hand panel (ctrl+shift+3 to bring it up); in the screenshot below I'm inspecting your username in the "asked by" section:

[image]

IMO Safari 6 inspection tool appears to be more powerful than ever, with a heavy focus on JS properties and DOM.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it is there. I am probably too used to Chrome's and I very much miss the display of which css file the rule is in (yes, I know I can hover on the arrow). This thread seems to confirm my suspicions: http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-1412447.html